# How to create a sidebar(right-side) in google chrome?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

It seems that it is not possible, but if anyone as a hint on how to create a right-sided sidebar (like a iframe) in google chrome, any hint will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like that

[image]

This is from the google chrome experimental api:

> Caution: Don't depend on these
>   experimental APIs. They might
>   disappear, and they will change. Also,
>   the Chrome Developer Dashboard doesn't
>   allow you to upload extensions that
>   use experimental APIs.

Details: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/user-experience/panels

Comment: this link is disappeared

Comment: @artworkadシ thanks for your reply but i didn't get any link regarding this can you suggest me any link and thnks for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

The experimental sidebar API has, as of this time, disappeared from the chrome documentation, since there is no longer a developer working on it.

Your best bet for something that you can achieve now is a DOM bar, as discussed in [Creating a StumbleUpon-like toolbar for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026867/creating-a-stumbleupon-like-toolbar-for-chrome)