# How can I specify a sidebar in Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

I'm trying to add a sidebar (experimental) to my extension.

I've enabled the "Experimental Extension APIs" in Chrome.

When I invoke:

```
chrome.experimental.sidebar.show(cTab);
```

method, (where cTab is current tab) I get an error:

> Error during experimental.sidebar.show: This extension has no sidebar
>   specified.

When I invoke:

```
chrome.experimental.sidebar.getState(cTab, function (state) { alert(state); });
```

I get "undefined" in the alert box.

I read the specs of chrome.experimental.sidebar and I have no clue how to add a sidebar to Chrome.

How can I specify a sidebar for my extension? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First declare `sidebar` in your manifest:

```
{
    ...
    "sidebar": {},
    ...
}
```

Then to display `sidebar.html` in a current tab:

```
chrome.experimental.sidebar.show();
chrome.experimental.sidebar.expand();
chrome.experimental.sidebar.navigate({path: "sidebar.html"});
```

Here is [example extension](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/sidebar/test.js).

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer supported unfortunately.  See:

[How to create a sidebar(right-side) in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923910/how-to-create-a-sidebarright-side-in-google-chrome)

[Chrome.experimental.sidebar gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740448/chrome-experimental-sidebar-gone)

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51084

Hopefully they'll add it back new and improved in a future release.

You'll need to use the DOM injection approach.

Comment: Thanks for the link to my question! :D