# Creating a StumbleUpon-like toolbar for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, toolbar

How can I get to do this? I've read the documentation but I find I can only [have icon, a tooltip, a badge, and a popup](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest). And I want to make it a StumbleUpon-like toolbar. Then I thought about using ContentScripts but I don't know where to add the html to inject because according [to the documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html) I only have the options of js or css. What am I missing here?

I have a js file:

```
$("body").before('<div name="extension-top" id="extension-top"></div>');
var top = document.getElementById("extension-top");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginTop = '40px';
top.src = chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html");
```

and css:

```
#extension-top { width:100%; height:40px; top:0; left:0; background:#000;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

finally an html:

```
<body id="extension-content">
    HELLO
</body>
```

The bar shows up but the "hello" isn't anywhere to be seen =/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't just set `src` of a div and expect it to load that url into its body. Maybe `iframe` would be a better option?

If you want to go with the div then you will need to load popup.html content using `XMLHttpRequest` inside a background page, then pass that html to content script and inject it on the page (popup shouldn't have any `body` tags). Another disadvantage of div is that styling it would be pain in the neck as parent site's styles will interfere with yours.

PS. Also you shouldn't be injecting it above the `<body>`.

Comment: An iframe is definitely the way to go. Otherwise you are going to have a terrible time styling up your toolbar without influencing and being influenced by the CSS of the page that you are injecting it into.

Answer (score 1):

The very basics of it are, you need to inject a js script that creates the html elements and injects them into the page,

so, with a simple assumption that you are using jQuery something like

`var toolbar = $('<div id="toolbar">My Toolbar</div>').prependTo('body');`

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental Infobar API that you could use to make a StumbleUpon-like toolbar. See [Infobars](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.infobars.html) for documentation and examples.

Note that you won't be able to publish the extension to the Chrome Web Store until the API becomes stable.